# How to dd entire line and paste insert to other line without newline and space?

Tags: vim

for example:

```
  1:  if doc.text =~ /test/
  2:        content = doc.xpath('shoud be replaced') // this string in quotes will be replaced with `vi'p`
  3:    end
  4:    /html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[5] // dd this line
```

Step: `dd` line 4 and jump to line 2 then `vi'p`

if i `dd` the line 4 and paste to replace the string in the quotes with line 2, the line will contain linebreak and spaces, like following:

```
  1:  if doc.text =~ /test/
  2:        content = doc.xpath('
  3:   /html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[5]
     ')
  4:    end
```

how to avoid the linebreak and spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you put, rewrite the contents of the default register to trim whitespace, which you can do with

```
:let @@ = trim(@@)
```

By removing leading and trailing whitespace, including the trailing newline, the register will become character-wise (rather than linewise), so Vim won't break the line before the register's contents while putting it.

Alternatively, if you can control the time when you cut the contents, then use `D` to delete to newline, after going to the first non-blank character with `^`. A character-wise delete will end up in register `"-`, which won't be overwritten by a subsequent line delete (`dd` to delete the remaining whitespace in that last line), so later on you can put it with `"-p`.

Answer (score 1):

Variant 1:

```
4Gy$dd2Gvi'"0p
```

`4G` - go to the 4th line, 1st non-blank char (also you can use `_` or `^`)

`y$` - yank until (but not including) the end of line

...

`"0p` put last yanked text

Variant 2:

```
" hotkey to trim register
nnoremap <leader>t :call setreg(v:register, trim(getreg()))<CR>

4Gdd<leader>t2Gvi'p
```

Comment: @TangMonk See also `:h Y`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to "cast" register contents into a certain (characterwise / linewise / blockwise) mode so often, I wrote the [UnconditionalPaste plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) for it. It provides `gcp`, `glp`, etc. alternatives to the built-in paste commands that force a certain mode (and by now several more variations on this theme, like pasting with joined by commas or queried characters).

With it, you can just use `gcp` / `gcP` to paste after / before the cursor position, regardless of how you've yanked the text. Inner newline characters and indent are flattened to a single space, leading and trailing removed.